# Slow Query with LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, select, performance, postgresql-9.2, offset-fetch, postgresql-performance

We have this query:

```
SELECT "messages".*
FROM "messages"
WHERE "messages"."account_id" = 1
AND "messages"."status" = 'unread'
AND (created_at >= '2014-04-24 01:00:00.000000')
ORDER BY id DESC
```

It runs fine under 0.1ms. But when we add **LIMIT**:

```
SELECT "messages".*
FROM "messages"
WHERE "messages"."account_id" = 1
AND "messages"."status" = 'unread'
AND (created_at >= '2014-04-24 01:00:00.000000')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

It runs over 20,000ms. Some notes:

- The messages table has over 300,000 rows, not that big.
- We have indexes on all 3 columns in the WHERE condition.
- The **account_id** and **created_at** conditions filter out 3,000 messages from the 300,000 rows. Out of the 3,000 messages in that **account_id**, there are only 3 unread messages.

So we isolated each **WHERE** condition and found out about a certain behaviour -- we tweaked the **LIMIT** to correspond with the amount of unread messages:

```
SELECT "messages".*
FROM "messages"
WHERE "messages"."account_id" = 1
AND "messages"."status" = 'unread'
AND (created_at >= '2014-04-24 01:00:00.000000')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3
```

It runs under 0.100ms. Any explanation for the difference in performance?

Comment: Key to understanding are the respective query plans. Run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` post the output on http://explain.depesz.com/ and add the links to your question. You'll see different plans for the two queries.

Comment: can you post an ... explain (costs true, buffers true, analyze true) SELECT ... of both queries?
it will reveal the problem. fixing it should be easy them. many thanks, hans

Answer (score 2):

Adding `LIMIT` to the query often makes Postgres choose a different query plan. If **statistics** or **cost estimates** stray too far from actual data distribution / actual costs, you may end up with a slower query, even though Postgres reckoned it would be faster. Irregular data distribution may cause the query planner to misjudge the selectivity of `WHERE` conditions.

In particular, increasing the `STATISTICS` target for `status`, `account_id`, `created_at` and `id` might help.

Details:

- [How can I avoid PostgreSQL sometimes choosing a bad query plan for one of two nearly identical queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228326/how-can-i-avoid-postgresql-sometimes-choosing-a-bad-query-plan-for-one-of-two-ne/8229000#8229000)

Aside from that, a [(partial) multi column index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html) may help. Depends on the complete situation. Which of your `WHERE` conditions are constant? How can they vary? Is some additional maintenance cost and disk space acceptable for a special index?

For example:

```
CREATE INDEX messages_special_idx ON messages (account_id, created_at, id)
WHERE status = 'unread'
AND   created_at >= '2014-01-01 01:00:00';
```

Run `ANALYZE messages;` before you try your queries again.