# Slow PostgreSQL 9.6.5 query with LIMIT, but only for tsquery with no results

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-performance

Table `a` has > 3 million rows and this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_a_txt
  ON a
  USING gin
  (txt);
```

This query takes 5 seconds if I search for something that *doesn't* exist, and 31 milliseconds if I search for something that does:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a.txt @@ to_tsquery('simple_english', $1)
LIMIT 10
```

The query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..847.17 rows=10 width=1285)
->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..560995.49 rows=6622 width=1285)
        Filter: (txt @@ '''test'''::tsquery)
```

If I leave off the `LIMIT 10`, the results are reversed: In the non-existing case, it takes 12 milliseconds, but in the existing case, it takes > 30 seconds (naturally, because it's trying to return 50,000 rows.)  Anyway, the query plan instead is:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on a  (cost=1839.32..26016.86 rows=6622 width=1285)
Recheck Cond: (txt @@ '''blahblahblah'''::tsquery)
->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_a_txt  (cost=0.00..1837.67 rows=6622 width=0)
        Index Cond: (txt @@ '''blahblahblah'''::tsquery)
```

I've run ANALYZE on table `a` as suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/80992/28774) but the results are still as above.

If I instead `SELECT COUNT(*)` I get `50000` back in 150 milliseconds, or `0` back in 12 milliseconds.

Is there any way to make such a query work quickly whether there are results or not?

## Reproducible example

Not quite the 5s, but 2s still vs 12-31ms, so you get the idea, at least:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY simple_english (
   TEMPLATE = simple,
   stopwords = 'english'
);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english (
  PARSER = "default"
);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR asciihword WITH simple_english;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH simple_english;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR email WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR file WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR float WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR host WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR hword WITH simple_english;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR hword_asciipart WITH simple_english;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR hword_numpart WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR hword_part WITH simple_english;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR int WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR numhword WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR numword WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR sfloat WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR uint WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR url WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR url_path WITH simple;
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION simple_english ADD MAPPING FOR version WITH simple;

drop table if exists a;
create table a (id text,
  b text NOT NULL,
  c text,
  d timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  e text NOT NULL,
  f timestamp with time zone,
  g timestamp with time zone,
  h integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  i integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  j text,
  k text,
  l text,
  m text,
  n timestamp with time zone,
  o text NOT NULL,
  p text,
  q timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  r timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  s text,
  t character varying(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'fb'::character varying,
  txt tsvector
);
CREATE INDEX idx_a_txt
  ON a
  USING gin
  (txt);
insert into a (id, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, txt)
SELECT uuid_in(md5(random()::text || now()::text)::cstring), 'foobar', 'foobar2', now(), md5(random()::text), now(), now(), random()*100, random()*100, random()::text, random()::text || ' ' || random()::text, random()::text || ' ' || random()::text, '', null, (random()*100000)::text, '', now(), now(), '', 'fb', to_tsvector('simple_english', md5(random()::text))
FROM generate_series(1,3400000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> This query takes 5 seconds if I search for something that doesn't exist, and 31 milliseconds if I search for something that does:

Well of course, you have `LIMIT 10`. In the event you have something you can stop searching *immediately*. In the event you do not find 10 things, you have to search the entire index or table.

Comment: This makes sense, except that searching an index shouldn't take 5 seconds.  If I use `select count(id)`, for example, I get `0` back in 12 ms, or for something that exists, `50000` comes back in 162 ms.

Comment: @Kev no idea what you're doing perhaps you can extract out a test case?

Comment: The OP was already distilled, but I don't have any generated test data on hand.  I'll try to make some and get back to you.  Meanwhile I added the above details to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added an approximation of the table with random data.  It performs a better than real life, but the orders of magnitude are the same.